# jinja2 Can't slice elements

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

I am trying to retrieve some data from a django database. I filter through the database with a query which I use to get a query set. I then pass this set into template by setting results to the query set.

```
    {% for result in results %}
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{result.name}}</h5>
                <ul class="card-text">
                    {% for item in (result.item_set.all)[:5] %}
                    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Go To</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I would like to have the first five elements of the item set. The query set holds a bunch of parent tables which have foreign keys to a different table. Think of it like I have a set of a bunch of people and I can get each person's name and all of their pets' names. Maybe someone has a lot of pets so I'd only want the first 5 of them. However, I am getting this error here that says
`TemplateSyntaxError at /results`
`Could not parse the remainder: '(result.item_set.all)[:5]' from '(result.item_set.all)[:5]'`

I don't understand this at all since I try looking for other problems like this and they are able to use the [:5] fine. Everything works until I introduce the [:5].

Comment: why not limit the number of items from the views ? It is not advisable to override the queryset because it causes inconsistency, but you can create a new variable ... set the value from the queryset and then limit the numbers in that variable and pass it through the context dictionary

Comment: I could do that but I'm just not getting why I can't splice it in the template. It works for everyone else so why not mine?